# Rewrite URL with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite this URL:

```
https://example.com/forms/cus_F8fylX6aITpJOR
```

to

```
https://example.com/assets/forms/redirect.php?id=cus_F8fylX6aITpJOR
```

Here what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\w+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^assets/forms/redirect.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Where's my mistake ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you'll need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forms/([^/]+) /assets/forms/redirect.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```